# How to index a value into string when it has multiple curly braces and %

Tags: python

I want to place a value into a string, however I cannot access the string as a `f-string` because it has multiple curly braces, but also I cannot use the following `%s` to access a value in the string as it has multiple `%` operators.

Here's an example string:

```
string = '{{id,name,tagline,frequency,duration,price,formattedPrice,pricePerUnit,formattedPricePerUnit}oneTimePurchase{index}}priceRange(withSubscriptionPriceRange:true),@include(if:$withPriceRange){fromPriceFormatted}discount{mode,value}currency,weight,seoJson}}}&v=%7B%22slug%22%3A%22p8-by-olly-fathers%22%2C%22externalId%22%3A%22%22%2C%22withPriceRange%22%3Afalse%7D'
```

I wanted to include the following string:

```
firstRange
```

inside the following part of the string:

```
externalId%22%3A%22%2firstRange%2C%22withPriceRange%22%3Afalse%7D
```

I have tried using:

```
string % "firstRange"
```

Aftering inserting `%s` in the required position but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: unsupported format character 'B' (0x42)
```

Comment: You can escape a brace in an f-string by prefixing it with another matching brace: `f'{{foo}}' == '{foo}'`

Comment: Why are you using `%` for string formatting? This is super old. At the very list use the `str.format` method and for Python >= 3.6 use f-strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
P = '%22%3A%22%22'
F = 'firstRange'
string = '{{id,name,tagline,frequency,duration,price,formattedPrice,pricePerUnit,formattedPricePerUnit}oneTimePurchase{index}}priceRange(withSubscriptionPriceRange:true),@include(if:$withPriceRange){fromPriceFormatted}discount{mode,value}currency,weight,seoJson}}}&v=%7B%22slug%22%3A%22p8-by-olly-fathers%22%2C%22externalId%22%3A%22%22%2C%22withPriceRange%22%3Afalse%7D' 

if (idx := string.find(P)) >= 0:
    string = string[:idx+len(P)] + F + string[idx+len(P):]
    print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using double curly brackets you can "escape" them:

```
'{hi} {}'.format('hey') #don't use this, instead use:
'{{hi}} {}'.format('hey')
```

So for your case:

```
string = '{{{{id,name,{}#ADDEDTHISFORTESTINGtagline,frequency,duration,price,formattedPrice,pricePerUnit,formattedPricePerUnit}}oneTimePurchase{{index}}}}priceRange(withSubscriptionPriceRange:true),@include(if:$withPriceRange){{fromPriceFormatted}}discount{{mode,value}}currency,weight,seoJson}}}}}}&v=%7B%22slug%22%3A%22p8-by-olly-fathers%22%2C%22externalId%22%3A%22%22%2C%22withPriceRange%22%3Afalse%7D'

string = string.format('test')
print(string)
```

Output:

```
{{id,name,test#ADDEDTHISFORTESTINGtagline,frequency,duration,price,formattedPrice,pricePerUnit,formattedPricePerUnit}oneTimePurchase{index}}priceRange(withSubscriptionPriceRange:true),@include(if:$withPriceRange){fromPriceFormatted}discount{mode,value}currency,weight,seoJson}}}&v=%7B%22slug%22%3A%22p8-by-olly-fathers%22%2C%22externalId%22%3A%22%22%2C%22withPriceRange%22%3Afalse%7D
```

Notice that 'test' was added as the 3rd word in place of the two curly brackets I added:

```
'{}#ADDEDTHISFORTESTING' #this
#changed to:
'test#ADDEDTHISFORTESTING' #this
#via
string = string.format('test')
```